# SIGTRAP on set background color

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a swift view controller that is a subclass of JSQMessagesViewController and I'm seeing a weird SIGTRAP in `viewDidLoad`. Namely it occasionally happens when I try to set the background color. It happens sporadically so I'm not sure what might be happening.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Here's the crash log:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   MyApp                                0x00000001000ecc74 MyApp.MessageDetailViewController.viewDidLoad ()() (MessageDetailViewController.swift:130)

1   MyApp                                0x00000001000ecc94 @objc MyApp.MessageDetailViewController.viewDidLoad ()() (MessageDetailViewController.swift:0)

2   UIKit                                0x0000000187834b40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 992

3   UIKit                                0x0000000187834744 -[UIViewController view] + 24

4   UIKit                                0x00000001878f4f88 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 308
5   UIKit                                0x00000001878f4238 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 140
6   UIKit                                0x00000001878f3ddc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 864
7   UIKit                                0x00000001878f3a04 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
8   UIKit                                0x00000001878f396c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 204
9   UIKit                                0x00000001878300e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 652
10  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851d6a28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
11  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851d1634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 288
12  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851d14f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
13  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851d0b24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 248
14  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851d086c CA::Transaction::commit() + 508
15  QuartzCore                           0x00000001851c9dd8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
16  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001826a07b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
17  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018269e554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
18  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018269e984 __CFRunLoopRun + 924
19  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001825c8d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
20  GraphicsServices                     0x0000000183eb0088 GSEventRunModal + 176
21  UIKit                                0x000000018789df70 UIApplicationMain + 200
22  MyApp                                0x00000001000286b4 main (main.m:16)
23  ???                                  0x00000001821668b8 0x0 + 0
```

The controller is presented modally in a navigation controller but then can transition to being pushed onto the nav stack (similar to composing a message in the stock sms app). Maybe it is possible that the lack of animation is causing an issue?

```
   func controllerDidSendMessageInThread(controller: MessageDetailViewController, thread: Thread) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        let detail = MessageDetailViewController(thread: thread)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail, animated: animated)


    }
```

Comment: How does your view controller appear ?

Comment: It is in a navigation controller that can be presented modally or pushed onto an existing navigation stack.

Comment: Most probably something else causes the crash. Will do my best to help if  you share more code. Another suggestion is to isolate that view controller in a new project and make sure the crash happens

Comment: The only reason I think it is actually crashing here is that in the last version I shipped I moved this line of code in viewDidLoad() but the stack trace still pointed to the background color. I updated the question to add code showing how I present the VC